# Adding time to game played with chess engine

Tags: engines, time-control, time-management

Are there any chess engines out there that will allow me to add arbitrary amounts of time to their clocks as the game progresses? I am interested in experimenting with two engines playing each other with me manually (or programatically) giving each bonus time throughout the game according to an algorithm I've developed.

Comment: Good question. I don't know of a way to automatically get an engine's move after a certain amount of time, but you'd figure there's a way. Are you using chessbase?

Comment: Right now it seems my best bet has been with Arena. You can manually add time to the clock with that program but it appears as though if you add it to one player's clock, then it automatically gets added to the other player's clock as well.

Comment: One possible solution would be changing their source code yourself if you have experience with programming (assuming the engines are open source like Stockfish). That's probably too extreme though.

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion and I actually am a programmer by trade, but was worried the task would be too daunting. But perhaps it's worth a try.

Comment: The C++ code for Stockfish is fairy daunting... lots of bit shifting if I recall :) But if you have experience with the language I don't imagine it'd be too difficult to sift through the code.

Comment: just to clarify, you should not focus on the actual chess engine but on the UCI interface talking to the engine

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure on this, but if you go on [Lichess](https://lichess.org), there is an option to add 15 seconds to your opponent's clock in live chess, I do not know with computer chess. I usually use [Chess.com](https://chess.com)'s live chess VS a bot.